# Need solution to react.js carousel

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working with React-slick carousel (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick)
I have the carousel working but the situation is that I am unable to create arrows (left, right) as well as center the images.  I have tried `centerMode: 'true'` in my `Setting` variable and this does not work.  My second thought was to just use CSS but this does not work either. I would like to use Flex Box.

If you have any suggestion please Let me know!  Thanks

Comment: It would be _very_ helpful if you could edit in your current code. Even better, [open up a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so we can understand the issue a lot better. Without that, the most we can do is guess

Comment: have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560980/5124488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Glidejs](https://glidejs.com/)

A dependency-free JavaScript ES6 slider and carousel. It works with react.

And check the **peek** option.Its like a center mode [Peek option](https://glidejs.com/docs/options/)