# GlideJS - Weird behavior when using slide with React Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, glidejs

I'm using GlideJS with a React Project, but it's returning a strange behavior. The components are not showing one per view and the width of them is changed.

[image: Strange Behavior]

The Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Glide from "@glidejs/glide";

export default class SliderGlide extends Component {
  state = { id: null };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // Generated random id
    this.setState(
      { id: `glide-${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)}` },
      this.initializeGlider
    );
  };

  initializeGlider = () => {
    this.slider = new Glide(`#${this.state.id}`, this.props.options);
    this.slider.mount();
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps = newProps => {
    if (this.props.options.startAt !== newProps.options.startAt) {
      this.slider.go(`=${newProps.options.startAt}`);
    }
  };

  render = () => (
    <div
      id={this.state.id}
      className="mt-10"
      style={{ overflowX: "hidden", userSelect: "none", maxWidth: "100vw" }}
    >
      <div className="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
        <button
          className="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left rounded-full"
          data-glide-dir="<"
          title="Veja mais ofertas!"
        >
          <span className="hidden">Anterior</span>
        </button>
        <button
          className="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right rounded-full"
          data-glide-dir=">"
          title="Veja mais ofertas!"
        >
          <span className="hidden">Próximo</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
        <div className="glide__slides" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {this.props.children.map((slide, index) => {
            return React.cloneElement(slide, {
              key: index,
              className: `${slide.props.className} glide__slide`
            });
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
        {this.props.children.map((slide, index) => {
          return <button key={index} className="glide__bullet rounded-full" data-glide-dir={"=" + index} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

SliderGlide.defaultProps = {
  options: {}
};
```

So inside of the Carousel component, i pass the childrens and the options for glide, that are the components.

```
const Plans = ({ plans, handleOffer }) => {
  const carouselOptions = {    type: 'slide',
  perView: 1,
  startAt: 0,


}

 return (
    <div className="section__slider relative mt-10 flex justify-center items-center">
        <Carousel options={carouselOptions}>
      { plans.map((plan, i) => {
         return (
            <OfferProduct key={i} i={i} plan={plan} handleOffer={handleOffer}/>

          )
        })
        }
        </Carousel> 
        </div>
        ) 
 }
export default Plans;
```

I want to know if the problem is related to my code, some missed styledsheet that i need to import or if the actions passed to glide are wrong.

Comment: can you set up a code sandbox? I will give a try

Comment: i can't because it is private, but there's a stage url where you can check with the dev tools :/ http://stage.claro.tkoa.me/combo/ofertas - CEP: 88090220 - Número 88

Comment: let me check it

Comment: Does the solution below work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just set up the full working demo for you using `glidejs` with `React`. check it out and let me know whether it works for you. [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-lovelace-1viwf)

[image: awesome glide GIF]

**index.js**

```
class Plans extends Component {
  state = {
    myPlans: [
      { id: 0, text: "plan 0", price: 0 },
      { id: 1, text: "plan 1", price: 1 },
      { id: 2, text: "plan 2", price: 2 },
      { id: 3, text: "plan 3", price: 3 }
    ]
  };
  handleOffer = id => {
    console.log("handleOffer clicked, id: ", id);
  };

  render() {
    const carouselOptions = { type: "slide", perView: 1, startAt: 0 };

    return (
      <div className="home-section test">
        <SliderGlide options={carouselOptions}>
          {this.state.myPlans.map(plan => (
            <OfferProduct
              key={plan.id}
              plan={plan}
              handleOffer={this.handleOffer}
            />
          ))}
        </SliderGlide>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Plans;
```

**OfferProduct.js**

```
const OfferProduct = ({ plan, handleOffer }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => handleOffer(plan.id)} className="card">
        <p>
          <h3> Card no: {plan.id} </h3>
          <span>price: {plan.price}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default OfferProduct;
```

**SliderGlide.js**

```
export default class SliderGlide extends Component {
  state = { id: null };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // Generated random id
    this.setState(
      { id: `glide-${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)}` },
      this.initializeGlider
    );
  };

  initializeGlider = () => {
    this.slider = new Glide(`#${this.state.id}`, this.props.options);
    this.slider.mount();
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps = newProps => {
    if (this.props.options.startAt !== newProps.options.startAt) {
      this.slider.go(`=${newProps.options.startAt}`);
    }
  };

  render = () => (
    // controls
    <div id={this.state.id} className="slider">
      <div className="two-controls-btns" data-glide-el="controls">
        <button className="arrow-left" data-glide-dir="<" title="start">
          <span className="hidden">Start</span>
        </button>
        <button className="arrow-right" data-glide-dir=">" title="end">
          <span className="hidden">End</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      {/* track  */}
      <div className="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
        <div className="glide__slides" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {this.props.children.map((slide, index) => {
            return React.cloneElement(slide, {
              key: index,
              className: `${slide.props.className} glide__slide`
            });
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* bottom bullets */}
      <div className="bottom_bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
        {this.props.children.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <button
              key={index}
              className="single-bullet"
              data-glide-dir={"=" + index}
              title=".g"
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

SliderGlide.defaultProps = {
  options: {}
};
```

**styles.css**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-section {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.card {
  width: 50px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: violet;
  padding: 10px;
}

.slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
.arrow-left,
.arrow-right {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.two-controls-btns {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.single-bullet {
  background-color: #080f47;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.bottom_bullets {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.test {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: thanks, now is so much better than before. my idk why is not sliding :( http://stage.claro.tkoa.me/combo/ofertas

Comment: I just checked, it's not sliding for you. Did you remove some of the attributes of glide? Can you share the snippets I will definitely look into it. I think you have removed top buttons controls I.e. data-glide-el ="controls" and data-glide-el="track". These attributes are necessary.

Comment: i didn't remove any of the attributes. but i'm seeing that the error maybe is because the class - glide__slide--active, always stays in the first component, and it's not changing while the slide action

Comment: those are for css classnames. I think those are not from `glidejs`. so you can remove them and add your own styles like I did. you should not remove attributes starting from `data-glide-`

Comment: check the code sandbox, I have removed unused classnames those are not starting with `data-glide-`. it works the way it should.

Comment: one of your `OfferProduct` classnames shows `undefined`. I don't why

Comment: https://github.com/glidejs/glide/issues/307#issuecomment-502729940